# Informatica Powercenter Repository location inside the physical machine

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have installed informatica version 10.2,everything is running and working fine.
I have created two informatica powercenter repositories name: `PRS_3`, `PRS_F2` from cliet side.
These repostories are present in domain as well in administrative console.

Snap:
[image: Informatica Repos]

I want to know where these two Repos are stored  `PRS_3`, `PRS_F2` in physical machine.

I checked in informatica installation in server side, dir but I didnot find these files.are repos stored in client side??

```
[ ~]$ cd informatica_installation/
[informatica_installation]$ ls
install.sh  properties    Server                     SilentInput_upgrade_NewConfig.properties  silentinstall.sh  upgrade_utils
logs        sapsolutions  SilentInput_DT.properties  SilentInput_upgrade.properties            source
Messages    saptrans      SilentInput.properties     silentinstallDT.sh                        unjar_esd.sh
[informatica_installation]$ cd source/
[source]$ ls
connectors  DataTransformation  DiskSpaceInfo.properties  externaljdbcjars  isp  java  ODBC7.1  plugins  server  services  thirdpartynotice  tomcat  tools
[ModelRepositoryService]$ ls
activation-1.1.jar                                                                                lucene-queryparser-4.3.0.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar                                                                        lucene-sandbox-4.3.0.jar
com.infa-com.infa.products.platform.modelutil.common-metamodel-10.2.0.9.490-SNAPSHOT.jar          lucene-snowball-2.4.1.jar
com.infa-com.infa.products.repository.prs.deployer.isp.service-10.2.0.82.490-SNAPSHOT.jar         lucene-spatial-4.3.0.jar
[ ModelRepositoryService]$ cd ..
[ services]$ ls
AdministratorConsole      DataArchiveService      HumanTaskService      ISPPlugins              PowerExchange     SearchService  WebAppApplicationService
AnalystService            DataIntegrationService  IDDService            MetadataManagerService  resourcemanager   shared         WebServiceHub
CatalogService            DQContent               InfaHadoopService     ModelRepositoryService  SAPBWService      TDMService
ContentManagementService  EmailService            IntelligentDQService  OAuthWebService         SchedulerService  Tutorial
```

OS: Linux for server side, Windows for client side.
Let me know the physical location of Repositories created by informatica powercenter Repositories services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Informatica Power Center(10.x) uses a client-server architecture where metadata is stored in a database and executables exists in physical server(called as Node).
If you want to know where is `PRS_3` repository service, go to Admin console > properties. You will see DB info.

Refer to below picture - in your case
Informatica services like Integration service and Repository service- runs in your Linux box where executables exists or wherever you installed infa.

Repo and Domain metadata - exists in a relational DB(Oracle/SQL Server etc.).

PC Clients - they can be installed in Windows machine. They talk to services and services talk to metadata base and completes a request.

[image: Architecture]